# SSH terminates randomly

Tags: ssh, putty

I have been using Putty on Windows to connect to Ubuntu instances on AWS and Google Cloud without issues. I could leave the session alone all day and they were never broken (if my PC does not lose network connectivity).

Lately, I have spun up another Ubuntu instance on AWS, in the same zone as an existing one that works fine. Putty sessions to this instance gets terminated every now and then. There do not seem to be a fixed interval before the connection is broken. The error is:

[image]

`ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` on this machine are the same as the other instances, ie commented out. I changed `ClientAliveInterval` to 60 on this problematic machine, but the issue does not go away.

I don't think it is a network issue as another Ubuntu in the same AWS zone simply stays connected. Where else can I troubleshoot to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain it is not a settings issue in Windows or Ubuntu then, maybe:

- it is a random failure in the connection?
- a defect in the Putty / Windows stack?

The second hypothesis could be tested easily.  Maybe try a different client, such as terminal in MacOS or Ubuntu with the problematic session and report test results?

Comment: Windows also now has an ssh client built in that could be tried for the "different client" test. In a command prompt terminal type, for example, `ssh doug@s19` (changing your user name and remote ssh server name, of course)

Comment: @DougSmythies  Good comment.   I would suggest trying to ssh from Ubuntu so as to isolate the fault.   An Ubuntu USB stick can be quickly booted on most PCs and a stable SSH client can be use to test.